# std::cin inside a infinite while loop in C++

Tags: c++

This doesn't work as i intended it. Please point me what i am doing wrong here.

The program is supposed to follow the steps below. But instead, it loops infinitely without waiting for inputs (except for the first time through the loop).

1. it prompts me and wait for inputs (integers).
2. it reads 4 integer inputs to an empty vector.
3. it prints out the elements inside the vector.
4. clear out data inside the vector.
5. repeat.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int> list;

  while(true){
      cout << "Enter four integers:" << '\n';
      // read 4 inputs to the empty vector while making sure there's data to read
      for (int x; cin >> x && list.size() < 4;) list.push_back(x);
      // prints out elements in the vector
      for (int x : list) cout << x << '\n';
      // clear the data inside the vector
      list.clear();
    }
}
```

> *As some have suggested, i changed the code to limit readings to 4*

New: `for (int x; cin >> x && list.size() < 4;) list.push_back (x);`
Old: `for (int x; cin >> x;) list.push_back (x);`

**NOTE :**
If i give four integers `1 2 4 6` followed by Ctrl-D, the problem persists but somehow if i give 5 or more inputs, it reads first 4 of those inputs and the program works just fine. Could someone plz explain why it acts this way ?

Comment: How would the code know to stop after 4 ints, as opposed to asking for a fifth and sixth ?

Comment: how is it intended to work?

Comment: How are you feeding it input, and what input are you feeding it? What is it doing? What did you expect it to do? Why do you have an infinite loop that never clears `list`? All of these are critical components of a [MCVE], and you've included almost none of them.

Comment: When i run the program it prompt me for input only one time and then iterates through the loop infinitely without waiting for inputs

Comment: we can see the code and we can compile it to see what it does. What we cannot see is your input and what the code should do instead.

Comment: `for (int x = 0; cin >> x;) list.push_back(x);` This is an infinite loop (assuming no errors on the stream). I'm not sure why you think it is not. When do you think this loop will terminate?

Comment: `This doesn't work as i intended it to work.` The thing is that you haven't said what you intended the code to do, and it certainly isn't obvious. So its hard to tell you what your mistake is because it's hard to figure out what you wanted.

Comment: So I'm going to take a guess. I think that you are waning to type in four numbers on one line and you expected the program to stop asking for input and start printing the results after the first line of numbers. Unfortunately that's not how it works. If you want to read a line, use `getline`, if you want to read N numbers then count them and stop reading when you get to N. That's how it works.

Comment: If i rewrite the code above without nesting inside the `while(true){ }` infinite loop, it works fine. btw i am giving `1 2 3 4` as the input followed by Ctrl-D.

Comment: @C4se `It works fine` Nowhere have you said what you expect this code to do. I'm sure you know but everyone else is guessing.

Comment: I am actually a little over 100 pages on the "Stroustrup-PPP" book and the way i am reading inputs into a vector in this code was used in the book. I apologise if i am wasting everyone's time here. I am new to programming and this is my first programming book.

Comment: @C4se Nothing wrong with being a beginner or with asking basic questions, but you have to appreciate that just saying 'its not working' is not a good way to ask. What we always say is, post the code, post the input, post the output you see, and explain what you expected to see instead. That way there is no doubt. Unfortunately very few beginners manage to do this (even when asked).

Comment: @john i apologise. I made some changes to my question and hope that's sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. i found a way to work around this while having a sensible and fair mind about what i've been doing wrong in my code.

First of all the everything i am saying from here to below are coming from a person so new to C++ and to programming in general. And my English skill is barely sufficient to survive the day.

Everyone was right about limiting number of readings the code performs cause when `std::cin` out of data, it reads an error (i guess, i am not sure at least for now). And after limiting readings the problem was still there. And i guess it's because after all in the line `for (int x; cin >> x && list.size() < 4;) list.push_back(x);`, the first condition that is being checked is `std::cin >> x` and it reads an error when you reach the end of file (EOF). After i change the the code to check the number of reading condition first `for (int x; list.size() < 4 && cin >> x;) list.push_back(x);`, the `list.size() < 4` condition is checked first and when it fails it doesn't go and check the `cin >> x` condition because i am using the `&&` AND operator here. That solved my problem. Thank you so much for everyone's time that has put in this thread. I apologise for not making my question clear at first.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int> list;

  while(true){
      cout << "Enter four integers:" << '\n';
      // read 4 inputs to the empty vector while making sure there's data to read
      for (int x; list.size() < 4 && cin >> x;) list.push_back(x);
      // prints out elements in the vector
      for (int x : list) cout << x << '\n';
      // clear the data inside the vector
      list.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int> list;

  while(true){
      // infinit loop that (every time going through the loop) ask for integers 
      // and push them into a vector and display the elements of the vector.

    cout << "Enter four integers (seperated by a space):" << '\n';

    int x = 0; 
    list.clear();
    while(list.size() < 4){
        cin >> x;
        list.push_back(x);
    }

    for (int x : list) cout << x << '\n'; 

    break; // Put rest of the code here    
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best guess at what the OP actually wants. The loop would be slightly better written as `while (list.size() < 4 && cin >> x) { list.push_back(x); }` so you don't try to add invalid input onto the list.

Comment: This does exactly what i intended, but i want to know what am i doing wrong in the way i am doing it. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: In your initial implementation, as long as `cin` reads a valid value, the `for` loop will not exit. You are typically missing a condition to tell you that you already have four integers stored to exit the loop, for instance `for (int x = 0; cin >> x && list.size() < 4;) list.push_back(x);`.

Comment: @LoW that makes sense but
1.  `for (int x = 0; cin >> x ;)` works fine when not nested inside the infinite `while` loop.
2. Even after changing it to limit reading to 4 values, the problem still persist.

Answer (score 1):

So I am still not completely clear what you want. You say 'the problem persists', but what problem are you talking about? It's such basic information but you still haven't said what the problem is.

So I'm taking another guess, you are talking about the failure of your program to recover after Ctrl+D. You want to enter four numbers terminated by Ctrl+D and then you want the loop to restart and you to be able to enter four numbers again. If I haven't got that right then the rest of this answer is a waste of time.

Here's some code, the new line is commented.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int> list;

  while(true){

    cout << "Enter four integers:" << '\n';

    for (int x = 0; cin >> x;) 
      list.push_back(x);
    cin.clear(); // clear any error state on cin

    for (int x : list)
      cout << x << '\n';  

    list = {};
  }
}
```

The point here is that Ctrl+D is treated as the end of input and when `cin` encounters it goes into an error state. In this state reads will no longer work. Normally this isn't a problem because why would you want to read anything more after the end of input. But you apparently (possibly) do, so calling `cin.clear();` removes the cin error state and allows input to happen again.

Comment: The problem i was referring is when i run my program it loops infinity without waiting for inputs (except for the very first iteration) on each time through the loop.

Even after i limit the reading to some number, the problem persists. Your code replicate the same issue for me.

But when i limit the number of readings to `n` and give `n+1` or more inputs. The program reads `n` number of inputs and works just fine.

Comment: @C4se Not waiting for input indicates that `cin` is in the error state I mentioned in the answer above. I would have expected `cin.clear();` to solve that problem. I'm not sure why it isn't for you.

Comment: @C4se Maybe it's just a bad idea to use Ctrl+D to terminate your input. That might affect the console in a way that C++ can do nothing about. I suggest using some other way to indicate when you've finished your input.

Comment: your answer to my question is the one actually made me clear what i had done wrong in my code. Thank you so much for that. But unfortunately even after limiting the reading count and clearing out `std::cin`, the problem was still there. Maybe it doen't have anything to do with C++ but the way i am ending the input. But i've also tried giving a non-integer to stop the reading as well and also giving all four inputs separately pressing Enter key for following each (in this last case the prompt still wait for a 5th input.)

Comment: Could you refer the solution that i have given to my question in this thread ?. Should i use a different terminal emulator ? i am on mac os and using the native terminal emulator.